vuejs build Stay on DONE Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed
my vuejs build Stay on DONE Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed. there's no error in terminal, and in verbose mode i have the same output, despite creating the dist folder correctly, the command continues to run and this is causing problems when configuring my github actions, the step is never completed and the workflow ends up failing due to timeout
my package.json:
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service build",
    "build-dev": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service build --mode development",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@duoa/vue-color-picker": "^1.0.6",
    "apexcharts": "^3.45.1",
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "2.0.0-rc.11",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "sass-loader": "10",
    "v-mask": "^2.3.0",
    "v-money": "^0.8.1",
    "vue": "2.5.17",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.6.2",
    "vue-colour-picker": "^0.0.5",
    "vue-gravatar": "1.2.1",
    "vue-html2pdf": "^1.8.0",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-mq": "0.2.1",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.0.8",
    "vue-router": "3.0.1",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vue-toasted": "1.1.24",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.7",
    "vuex": "3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "3.12.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.5.17"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}


my vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack:{
        performance: {
            hints: false
        },
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                minSize: 10000,
                maxSize: 250000,
            }
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        port: 4000,
        public: '0.0.0.0:4000'
    },
    pluginOptions: {
        webpackBundleAnalyzer: {
            analyzerMode: "disabled"
        }
    },
}



Can you provide the workflow file of your GitHub action?

@MohammadMasoudi I don't believe it's something related to the workflow, this problem occurs locally and also happened in Vercel
